# A simple Java method not working

Tags: java, methods

Hello everyone I am a newbie with the java programming language and have been learning the use of methods, below is a simple method i wrote for adding two numbers but when I run the code, it doe not display any output, please what I am doing wrongly? the code should sum numbers from 2 to 4 in this case

```
//testing Java methods
    public class Methods {
       public static void main(String [] args) {
         int addition = add (2,4);
         System.out.println(addition);
      }

//the method for addition
      public static int add(int a, int b){
         int sum = 0;
         for (int i = a; a <= b ; i++)
           sum += i;
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int i = a; a <= b ; i++)
```

It should be

```
 for (int i = a; i <= b ; i++)
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response, it worked when I edited the code like you said, thanks once more

Comment: don't mention it.  This is the very thing you should remember when coding you should keep an eye on your variables.

Answer (score 1):

It was actually running into **infinite loop**.

try this program (change from `a <= b to i <= b`)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int addition = add(2, 4);
        System.out.println(addition);
    }

    // the method for addition
    public static int add(int a, int b) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = a ; i <= b ; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

**output**

```
9
```

Answer (score 0):

your for loop should be

```
for (int i = a; i <= b ; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//testing Java methods
public class Methods {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int addition = add(2,4);
        System.out.println(addition);
    }

    //the method for addition
    public int add(int a, int b){ // Place this method in the class.
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = a; i <= b ; i++){ // "a <= b" Has to be: i <= b
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

I think this is want you want.

The result will be:
2+3+4 = 9